# mvc application not working

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-2

I am new to asp.net mvc.I am working on a simple application using Asp.net mvc2.I have created a controller which will get the user inputs and display it.When i run my application its showing me this error.My code is as below.

```
  Server Error in '/' Application.
  The resource cannot be found.
```

**Controller**:

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayCustomer(Customer obj)
    {
        return View("DisplayCustomer",obj);
    }
```

**View**:

```
 <% using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayCustomer","test1",FormMethod.Post))
 { %>
 Enter customer id :- <%= Html.TextBox("Id",Model)%> <br />
 Enter customer code :- <%= Html.TextBox("CustomerCode",Model) %><br />
 Enter customer Amount :- <%= Html.TextBox("Amount",Model) %><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" />
<%} %>
```

**Model**:

```
     public class Customer
{
    private string _Code;
    private string _Name;
    private double _Amount;

    public string Code
    {
        set
        {
            _Code = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _Code;
        }
    }

    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return _Name;
        }
        set
        {
            _Name = value;
        }
    }

    public double Amount
    {
        set
        {
            _Amount = value;
        }
        get
        {
            return _Amount;
        }
    }
}
```

I am running my application as `/test1/DisplayCustomer`.I browsed the web to solve it but i didnt get any solution.Please let me know where i went wrong.

Comment: [HttpPost] is for posting the form. There should be one more action method

Comment: Check [Here](http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/418350/The-resource-cannot-be-found)

Comment: @slacker s i want to post the form.

Comment: But you didnt seem to handle the posted data in the action method. Anyway you need another action method with the same name

Comment: @slacker please refer this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/207797/Learn-MVC-Model-View-Controller-step-by-step-in-7#Lab 4:- Creating simple MVC data entry screen.this is what i am trying for..

Comment: Then where is step 2 in your code?

Comment: @slacker sorry its LAB5.

Comment: I think it is a mistake in that article. Better try some other sources..

Comment: @slacker then tell me how can i create a data entry screen to get the user input and display it using mvc.

Comment: Please check the answer below. You have to do use your own data processing method in the post action

Answer (score 1):

Remove [HttpPost]

```
public ActionResult DisplayCustomer()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

And for posting purpose include one more action method:

```
 [HttpPost] 
 public ActionResult DisplayCustomer(Customer obj)
        {
           //Code for processing post data

           return View("DisplayCustomer",obj);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I have a feeling there's a little confusion.

Think about it that way:

In your Controller, in this case, you must have at least TWO actions,

One (GET method) - Should be the action which gets the client request for the PAGE, and returns the proper html (View). This action should be decorated with [HttpGet] and the default name for it (for now use it) its Index:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View();
}
```

After you create this, make sure you create a proper View file that matches that name, in this case, Index.cshtml in the proper Views folder (if you're using Visual Studio you can just RIGHT CLICK the action in the controller, and then the 'Add View' option and it will do that for you.

The second action you should care about is the one which gets the request from the form in your page. this one is quite similar to the one you've already written.

For your issue- 
Start with creating the Index action in your controller, create the proper View file, build, and run - Index.cshtml should be rendered.

I'd recommend you to read some general materials about HTTP GET/POST methods and uses, and some materials about general MVC concept (MVC is a method, a way to work with- it's not just with ASP.NET, it's a general thing in programming world).

Hope that helped.

Answer (score 0):

try this in controller:

```
public ActionResult DisplayCustomer()
    {
        return View();
    }

 [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult DisplayCustomer(Customer obj)
    {
        return RedirecttoAction("DisplayCustomer",obj);
    }
```

try this in Action:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("DisplayCustomer",FormMethod.Post))
 { %>
 Enter customer id :- <%= Html.TextBox("Id",Model)%> <br />
 Enter customer code :- <%= Html.TextBox("CustomerCode",Model) %><br />``
 Enter customer Amount :- <%= Html.TextBox("Amount",Model) %><br />
 <input type="submit" value="Submit customer data" />
<%} %>
```

Answer (score 0):

The above simply doesn't work.  There is a red squiggly under the Html.TextBox("Id", Model) no matter what I do.  I have to remove the ,Model in order for it to work, and I don't need the first action or the [HttpPost] and it works great.